# Nested Try/Catch statements alternative

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have some code that consumes a webservice. Rather than retrieve a session key from the service each time, I want to try the response with a session variable I set, and if I get a 403 error get a new session key and try again.

In my limited mind nesting `try/catch` statements makes sense but I'm just good enough to realize there has to be a better way. I've read a few posts here mentioning things like `lambda expressions with using statements` and `Helpers`, but these may as well be gifts from an alien interplanetary science to me.

Always willing to learn I was wondering if anyone has suggestions (with details or links to details)? Everything here works, I just need a better way than nesting `try` statements (please and thank you). As always, you guys rock!

`public string getMySessionkey` goes to the server with login credentials to get a session key (required for all other inquiries) if there isn't a session key already set

`searchPacket = stringbuilder with parameters and session key`

```
if (Session["MySessionKey"] != null)
{
    sessionKee = Session["MySessionKey"].ToString();
}
else
{
    sessionKee = getMySessionkey(_cbE, _cbP);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("MySessionKey", sessionKee);
}

try
{
    mySearchResults = getResults(searchPacket.ToString());
    vbResultz += Server.HtmlEncode(mySearchResults) ;
}
catch (WebException wx)
{
    HttpWebResponse webresponse ;
    webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)wx.Response;

    switch (webresponse.StatusCode)
    {
       case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
            ...
            break;

        case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden: // 403
            vbResultz = "You aint got no valid session key!";
          // code here to get a new session key and try again

            break;

        default:
            throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop with a limited occurences number. As soon as your call works, exit the loop.

```
var maxNumberOfTries = 3;
var currentTry = 0;
var success = false;

do
{
    currentTry += 1;

    // Try whatever here. If it works, set success variable to true

    if (success) break;
} while (currentTry <= maxNumberOfTries)

if (!success)
{
    // If code reaches here, whatever had to be done has been tried <maxNumberOfTries> times and did not work
}
```

EDIT: Here is the above sample implemented in your code:

```
var maxNumberOfTries = 3;
var currentTry = 0;
var flag = false;

do
{
    currentTry += 1;

    try
    {
        mySearchResults = getResults(searchPacket.ToString());
        vbResultz += Server.HtmlEncode(mySearchResults) ;
        flag = true;
    }
    catch (WebException wx)
    {
        HttpWebResponse webresponse ;
        webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)wx.Response;

        switch (webresponse.StatusCode)
        {
           case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
            ...
                flag = true;
                break;

            case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden: // 403
                vbResultz = "You aint got no valid session key!";
              // code here to get a new session key and try again

                break;

            default:
                throw;
        }
    }
    if (flag) break;
} while (currentTry <= maxNumberOfTries)

if (!flag)
{
    // If code reaches here, whatever had to be done has been tried <maxNumberOfTries> times and did not work
}
```

Here the `flag` variable will be set to true on successful attempt to obtain a key, OR if an internal server error occurs. If you have 403 response it will try again, up to three times.

Comment: works like a charm, thanx so much. Still want to learn about lamba and helpers, though.

Comment: @user116923 I'm not quite sure how that would benefit you on that specific problem.